# Rules of creating REST services, examples, templates to production code in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, rules

Welcome, it's my first question on Stack, so hi everyone.

I'm completely new in Spring Boot and REST API and I have to create project with good project template (packages, classes, interfaces) and good project patterns, but I've never seen any REST project in SpringBoot. In this case I'd like to ask you to describe some good habits, rules, patterns and example of REST Api to GET some data from it and test some cases of use. I'd be gratefull for example of source from github or tutorial links.
Short questions at the end:

1) How should will be the behavior of api when request has no result? Empty page or error in header status or something else?

2) How should will be the behavior of api when request is wrong (not exist)?

Thanks for replies and regards,

Kamil

Comment: Start from this https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is just for providing REST the Spring way. There's nothing philosophically REST about it. It's not designed specifically for REST, rather it's designed to support good REST design.

Some things to consider for good REST design in general are:

The 3 levels of REST:

[Richardson Maturity Model](http://Richardson%20Maturity%20Model)
[Three Levels of the REST Maturity Model](https://www.infoq.com/news/2010/03/RESTLevels)

comes with some code samples:
[ETags for REST with Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/etags-for-rest-with-spring)

[Why would ETags set to a MUST requirement if you already have the resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423987/why-would-etags-set-to-a-must-requirement-if-you-already-have-the-resource)

[Understanding HATEOAS](https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS)

As for returning an empty result, is that an error? Is it exceptional to not find something? If not, don't raise an Exception and return an error. What you return depends on how you want to handle the unexceptional situation of a search returning nothing. You could return a 404 with some simple JSON explaining but 404 needs no explanation.

Requesting a non existent endpoint is obvious, the request won't even get to you as the server will return a 404.

The question of 'error' in general depends on the domain that REST represents. A search that find nothing isn't an error. A search on a 'name' field when the domain has no 'name' field is a client error and an exception.

So there are basically 3 areas to study.

1. REST concepts in general (verbs, levels, hypermedia etc)
2. How Spring supports those REST concepts
3. How to return responses (JSON, XML?) and handle errors when clients interact with your domain via your REST endpoints